# Stream microphone audio to LAN IP/ PoE speakers?

Tags: networking, audio, pulseaudio, lan

I have several IP PoE speakers and regular speakers with IP converters connected to common network switch on LAN.

What can I use or how can I set up my network so that microphone recorded audio from Linux computer gets streamed to all or selected IP speakers on the network (e.g., via their IP address)? I basically want to setup broadcasting system (e.g., to broadcast message to another room). If not from microphone, streaming any audio to IP speakers would be a great first step.

Is it something that can be handled by PulseAudio? Or is there some kind of management software available to controlling LAN speakers?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which [protocol(s)](https://gavv.github.io/articles/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/#protocols-and-networking) those speakers/converters will support.

PulseAudio has a RAOP module (Debian/Ubuntu package `pulseaudio-module-raop`) which can send audio to Apple AirPlay-capable devices.

RAOP sinks (= devices that can receive AirPlay audio) can be auto-discovered, so you might run `pacmd list-sinks` and find that your system already sees any AirPlay-capable devices. Likewise, you can use `pacmd list-sources` to identify the PulseAudio name for your microphone - you'll need that information.

You can use `pavucontrol` to interactively send any audio stream to any device that is detected by PulseAudio.

If you want to use a microphone, you might try loading a Pulseaudio loopback module to connect the microphone to the sink device:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source="<name of PulseAudio source>" sink="<name of sink>"
```

For Chromecast-compatible and other DLNA/uPnP-capable audio devices, there is [pulseaudio-dlna](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/how-to-stream-audio-to-chromecast-or.html) (check your distribution's package collection first, it may already be there).

With them, you'll need to start the `pulseaudio-dlna` process first so it can auto-discover any DLNA-capable devices. Because of the variety of DLNA-capable devices, you'll have the option of specifying various options to `pulseaudio-dlna`if you e.g. find that the default codec or bitrate selections produce bad results with particular hardware. After that, the procedures should be the same as with AirPlay-capable devices.

[The RTP protocol is also supported.](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index2h3) [This other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471222/258991) may have useful commands you may wish to study too.

With RTP, you can directly specify the name of the PulseAudio source to be used to the RTP sender module, so you won't need the loopback module here:

```
pactl load-module module-rtp-send source="<name of PulseAudio source>" mtu=1408 destination_ip=<IP address of RTP device>
```